# How to convert String to Date time and format it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a date and time in String format and want to convert it Datetime and then in String.

I have String format as - **(2023-04-06T20:34:53.981+00:00)**

and I want output like - **(07/04/2023 02:04:53 AM) and (Apr 7, 2023 02:04:53 AM)**

So how I can do this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code .. to formate the date time you have to use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
var datetime=DateTime.parse('2023-04-06T20:34:53.981+00:00');
var formateddate= DateFormat("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(datetime);
```

and yes you can find it just by google search

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)** package to format dates and times. Here's an example code snippet that shows how to convert the given string to a DateTime object and then format it into the desired string formats:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void dateTimeConversion() {
  String dateString = '2023-04-06T20:34:53.981+00:00';
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateString);

  // format 1: 06/04/2023 02:04:53 AM
  String formattedDateTime1 = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').format(dateTime);
  print(formattedDateTime1);

  // format 2: Apr 6, 2023 02:04:53 AM
  String formattedDateTime2 = DateFormat('MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a').format(dateTime);
  print(formattedDateTime2);
}
```